# Does anyone know how to do uploaded Image convert to base64 encoding in JMeter and send through HTTP body?

Tags: image, jmeter, base64, performance-testing, beanshell

I'm working on IM (Image Managment) system performance ATM and I'm facing dificulties to send image metadata (base64) to end point. Here we do not upload direct file to the server, We will send image metadata (base64) to the server side. If anyone can help me to resolve this much appriciate.

We have API sequence as follow

1. Image draft API (create)
2. Image update API (POST with metadata (base64)

basicall, in browser it will converted to the base64 and keep in browser memory, 2nd API will pick the image metadata from thier and send to the server in HTTP request. but in the browser I cannot see the post body data.

[image]

I wanted to send uploaded image to the server as base64 data and save it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) in order to convert the file containing the image into [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Example code:

```
vars.put('image', new File('/path/to/your/image.png').bytes.encodeBase64().toString())
```

then you can refer the Base64-encoded image file contents as `${image}` where required.

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I tried several ways to add this PreProcessor, But still failing, If you mind @Dmitri T can we have a quick call? I'm sorry to ask like this.